# Messing with the beginner coinFlip-why is this not putting multiple entries (using while) in chat?

Tags: javascript, math, while-loop

```
var coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random());
console.log(coinFlip);
```

The above either puts a 0 or 1 in chat. 
 
I just learnt about the while loop...if its true, then the code runs.

```
var yes=1;

while (yes<2) {
console.log("Yes");
}
```

The above code will run infinitely (putting Yes in chat) as yes will always be less then 2. If we can make yes into 2, it will end. So...

```
var coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random());

while (coinFlip < 1) {
console.log(coinFlip);
}
```

When I try to combine the two, it doesn't work. I'm using repl.it and it just goes on forever and forever until I stop it. Meaning (I believe) it's an infinite loop. But I don't see how. It should log 0's in chat until it hits 1 and then stop.

So what am I doing wrong?

Even if I declare coinFlip inside the while loop, it still doesn't work. I went a little further into teaching myself right now and I can see you can run the coinFlip script using the for loop (as in, run it until it runs 5 times), but I still really want to learn why you can't run it (using while) until it hits 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is you're setting a variable `coinFlip` to have a value of either 1 or 0, then running a while loop that keeps checking the same value and printing to the console. So 1 of 2 things will happen:

- either `coinFlip` will be 0 and your loop will run forever (because the value of `coinFlip` never changes; or
- `coinFlip` will be 1 and the `console.log` will not even execute because the while condition will be evaluated to `false`.

You need to move the random number generation inside the loop:

```
var coinFlip = 0; // 0 because we want to satisfy the condition (coinFlip < 1)

while (coinFlip < 1) {
  coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random());
  console.log(coinFlip);
}
```